# What kind of hand saw do I need to cut laminated chipboard to a reasonable finish?

Tags: saw

I would like to cut a 20cm line in laminated chip board, what is the best kinda of saw to do this? What ppi or tpi does it need?

(I know the finish will not be perfect, and to get the best results I need a circular saw)

Comment: Melamine laminate or a Formica type laminate?

Comment: @jack its laminated with plastic not metal

Comment: ...and both items listed by jack **are plastics.** Formica is a form of paper phenolic, melamine is more of a thin solid sheet plastic layer (no paper.) Circular saws are no guarantee of being the best at his - thy can chip out severely.

Comment: I've had the best luck using masking tape and a router, not a saw

Answer (score 2):

I find that I get a line free of chips if I heavily score the line with a sharp knife and then cut with a sharp saw so the teeth of the saw on one side follow the line.

That pre-cut edge stays clean but the other edge chips.

Not tried making two parallel cuts the width of the blade though…

Works when I am doing new kitchen worktops or that covered chipboard used by ikea etc.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great tip. But I don't have a saw, as still need saw advice

Comment: @Dan I have used a hand saw, fret saw and jig saw at various time for that task - care (aka skill) required with all 3. Purchase what you want.